# Change Roles Authorization to return custom error instead of redirecting

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have an application that uses Angular as client. I'm using a Jwt Authentication. I'm now implementing some roles and I'd like that when a User does not have the role, the server return a custom error to the client.

Startup.cs:

```
 services.AddJwtService();
 services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(config => { config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true; }).AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

JwtService:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddJwtService(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            var opt = sp.GetService<IOptions<Settings>>();
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(opt.Value.JwtKey);
            services
                .AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.SaveToken = true;
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidIssuer = "Issuer",
                    ValidAudience = "Audience",
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                };
            });
        return services;
    }
```

ControllerExample:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public class UsersController : JumpBaseController<UsersController>
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] CreateUserDto userDto)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Token creation:

```
//done after await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(loginDto.Username, loginDto.Password, true, false);
private async Task<string> GetToken(ApplicationUser user)
{
    var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_settings.Value.JwtKey);
    var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    var claims = new[]
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, guid),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.UniqueName, user.UserName),
    };
    identity.AddClaims(claims);
    HttpContext.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
    var tokenDescriptor = GetTokenDescriptor(user, key, claims);
    return tokenDescriptor;
}
```

When a user without the role Admin try to create a new User I want to return a custom error to the client and not to be redirected to a `AccessDenied` page

Comment: I would think you need to provide them a JWT with a generic/lower privileged claim  before checking for authorized access, then in the Admin controller have a check in there if the user does not have anything more than the generic claim. That way you can return either an Ok() IActionresult or switch to a redirect or whatever response you want.

Comment: Yeah, but I think/hope that could exist a way to do this in one easier way, like changing the behaviour of the validation, instead of redirect, return httpstatus 500 or something like that

Comment: Im sure you know this but you can create custom exception pages. This will let you catch certain exceptions, but I do not believe your JWT will throw an exception, since being unauthorized is not an exception. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-2.2